# jQuery validate require_from_group error message location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully been able to use the code in 
jsfiddle.net/y3qayufu/2/ to validate a group of fields but how can I display the error message in a specific location. I would like the error message to appear only once after the submit button has been pressed, preferably above the group, but possibly below.

Instead of this:

[image: Original message location]

I would like this:

[image: New message location]

Thanks

Comment: check my answer with a fiddle below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is a fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bayahiassem/sdx4ru4s/2/

If you can't open it, here the updated code:

**html** Only added an id to the h3

```
<form id="findproject_form" method="post" action="{$BASE_URL}findproject">
    <div class="bgtrans">
        <h3 id="header">Search By</h3>

        <div class="div_bg1">
            <div class="searchbg">
                <div class="seachbginputbg">
                    <input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Profession" id="Profession" name="Profession" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbg">
                <div class="seachbginputbg">
                    <input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Location" id="Location1" name="Location1" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbg" style="margin-right:0px;">
                <div class="seachbginputbg">
                    <input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Company" id="Company" name="Company" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div_bg2">
            <div class="searchbg">
                <div class="seachbginputbg">
                    <input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="Name" name="Name" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbg">
                <div class="seachbginputbg">
                    <input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Key Words" id="KeyWord" name="KeyWord" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbg" style="margin-right:0px;">
                <input class="bgbttn" type="submit" name="submit" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS** using errorPlacement :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });

    $("#findproject_form").validate({
        rules: {
            Profession: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
            },
            Location1: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
            },
            Company: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
            },
            Name: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
            },
            KeyWord: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        console.log(error[0].innerText);
            if(error[0].innerText == 'Please fill at least 1 of these fields.' && !errorshowed) {
            error.insertAfter("#header");
            errorshowed = true;
          }
        }
    });

    var errorshowed = false;

    $.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function (value, element, options) {
        var $fields = $(options[1], element.form),
            $fieldsFirst = $fields.eq(0),
            validator = $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") ? $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") : $.extend({}, this),
            isValid = $fields.filter(function () {
                return validator.elementValue(this);
            }).length >= options[0];

        // Store the cloned validator for future validation
        $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp", validator);

        // If element isn't being validated, run each require_from_group field's validation rules
        if (!$(element).data("being_validated")) {
            $fields.data("being_validated", true);
            $fields.each(function () {
                validator.element(this);
            });
            $fields.data("being_validated", false);
        }
        return isValid;
    }, $.validator.format("Please fill at least {0} of these fields."));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery validation `errorPlacement` function provided:

[JsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/y3qayufu/10/)

```
    $("#findproject_form").validate({
    rules: {
      ....
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $('label.error').remove();
        error.insertAfter("#submit_btn");
    }
});
```

*HTML:*

```
     <div class="searchbg" id="submit_btn" style="margin-right:0px;">
          <input class="bgbttn" type="submit" name="submit" value="" />
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on submit u can put in function definition

```
var valid=0;
$(this).find('input[type=text], select').each(function(){
if($(this).val() != "") valid+=1;
});
if(valid==0)
{
$('#myDiv').html("please fil atleast one of these");
}
```